# Combining 'para' and 'plain' footnotes using manyfoot

Tags: line-breaking, footnotes, bigfoot

Following my previous [question about adjusting the footnote layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203926/adjusting-the-footnote-layout-for-critical-edition) which was partially answered, I want to ask something more direct. Is there a way to get a functionality similar to **`\footnote+`** of `bigfoot` package using `manyfoot`?

I am using the `manyfoot` package in the **para** option for the footnotes of a critical edition. I want some notes to occupy a separate line. Until now I am using the command `\newline` at the end of the previous note and at the end of the 'lonely' note. Unfortunately, the additional vertical space is not calculated when LaTeX is deciding the page break, so the footnote may overlap with the page number at the footer of a page. The same happens also when I predefine a new footnote command which includes `\newline`.

I encountered the command **`\footnote+`** of the para option of the `bigfoot` package, which does exactly what I want. However, looking at the scarce documentation of the package I cannot find a way to implement it in my special case. I would like to stay to the `manyfoot` package, because I prefer the way its `para` option is working, in comparison to the `bigfoot` package.

Below I provide a MWE which shows the problem of the footnotes overlapping with the footer. Again, the example may seem exaggerating, but such behaviour does occur in quite a lot of my pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[para]{manyfoot}

\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\def\extrafootnoterule{\defaultfootnoterule}
\newfootnote[para]{A}
\newfootnote[para]{B}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\newcommand{\foota}[1]{
  \FootnotetextA{}{\textbf{\arabic{poemline}} #1}
}
\newcommand{\footb}[1]{
  \FootnotetextB{}{\textbf{\arabic{poemline}} #1}
}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\verselinenumbersleft
\settowidth{\versewidth}{ααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααα}

\chapter*{CANON I}
\poemlines{5}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]

\vin ᾠδὴ . \textit{Θαυμαστὸς ἐνδόξως ποιῶν τέρατα}\foota{heirm. α΄ EE 76, n. 108, Andreae\newline}

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν\newline}\\
τῶν θεωριῶν\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν\newline}\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\!

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τῶν \footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}θεωριῶν\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\\
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν\newline}\\
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν\newline}\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\\!

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\\
τῶν θεωριῶν \footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\\
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\!

\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After quite a few unsuccessful efforts, I decided that the only solution would be to change to `bigfoot`. I have adjusted a hybrid combination of `para` and `plain` options by defining a new command for the footnotes which utilizes the `\footnote+` command of the `bigfoot` package:

```
\usepackage[para]{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{}
\newcommand{\foota}[1]{\footnoteA{\textbf{\arabic{poemline}} #1}}
\newcommand{\footheirm}[1]{\footnoteA+{#1}}
```

The remaining issue concerning the `para` style of `bigfoot` package is reported [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207975/indentation-problem-with-the-para-option-of-bigfoot).

[Edit: close curly brace.]