# Change footmisc options midway through document

Tags: package-options, footmisc

I would like to be able to use the `para` option of `footmisc` in one chapter of my book and have it not be in use in another chapter. In the package documentation I don't see a command defined for making such a change — is there a regular workaround?

---

As requested by a commenter, below is a MWE to manually store the original footnote text and then redefine \footnote so that it the original footnote text is followed by a newline.

But this is a hack, rather than changing `footmisc` options mid-way through the document. I suppose `footmisc` doesn't actually allow for such changes.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
 
\begin{document}

\chapter{Use option para, as per Preamble}

First;\footnote{1st note} second.\footnote{2nd note}

\chapter{Turn off option para}

\let\origthefootnote\thefootnote
\renewcommand\footnote[1]{%
 \footnotemark%
  {\def\thefootnote{%
   \makebox[0pt]{\origthefootnote}%
   }%
   \footnotetext{#1\newline}%
  }%
 }

First;\footnote{1st note} second.\footnote{2nd note}

\end{document}
```

Second chapter's footnotes shown here:
[image: Second chapter's footnotes shown here]

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204669/combining-para-and-plain-footnotes-using-manyfoot

Comment: That and its preceding question deal with other packages than `footmisc`, however. I'm wondering if there's a way of doing this with `footmisc`.

Comment: This is probably possible with `footmisc` as well. Could you prepare an example document with two chapters and some footnotes as a starting point?