# Fix the footnote separation with bigfoot

Tags: spacing, footnotes, bigfoot

I am using the `bigfoot` package for the footnotes of a critical edition in the `verse` environment. I have defined two different footnotes (A and B). What I need is to fix the separation between them, i.e. the space from the last note of the A footnote until the footnote ruler above the B footnote. The problem is that this separation varies when the page breaks in different positions.

Since the page break is co-defined by the command `\\*` of the `verse` package (which precludes a page break; to avoid widows and orphans), the situation can become quite complex. Below I provide a MWE and an illustration of the problem. The code that "Redefines the space above and below the footnote rulers" was kindly provided by Maïeul [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203926/adjusting-the-footnote-layout-for-critical-edition).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[para]{bigfoot}
\def\extrafootnoterule{\defaultfootnoterule}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}
\def \mylinespacing {1.05}
\expandafter\def\csname @makefnbreak\endcsname{\unskip\linebreak[0]\quad}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Redefines the space above and below the footnote rulers
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\before}{2.52pt}%Space before rule
\newcommand{\after}{10.52pt}% Space after rule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%Redefine footnoterule
\hrule width 3cm
\kern \after}
% Change the space kept for rules+spaces around
\advance\skip\footins by \after
\advance\skip\footins by \before
% Not print the after space before the rule
\patchcmd{\@makecol}{\vskip \skip\footins}{\vskip \skip\footins\vskip-\after}{}{}
%load parafootskip
% Not print the after space before the rule
\patchcmd{\MFL@joinrule}{\@tempskipa\skip#5}{\@tempskipa\skip#5\advance\@tempskipa by -\after}{}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{}

\newcommand{\foota}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\linespread{\mylinespacing}%
\footnoteA{\textbf{\arabic{poemline}} #1}
\endgroup}
\newcommand{\footb}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\linespread{\mylinespacing}%
\footnoteB{\textbf{\arabic{poemline}} #1}
\endgroup}
\newcommand{\footheirm}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\linespread{\mylinespacing}%
\footnoteA+{#1}
\endgroup}

\hyphenpenalty = 10000
\exhyphenpenalty = 10000

\begin{document}
\verselinenumbersleft
\settowidth{\versewidth}{ααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααα}

\chapter*{CANON I}
\poemlines{5}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]

\vin ᾠδὴ . \textit{Θαυμαστὸς ἐνδόξως ποιῶν τέρατα}\footheirm{heirm. α΄ EE 76, n. 108, Andreae}

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τῶν θεωριῶν\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην}\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\!

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τῶν \footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}θεωριῶν\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\\
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\\!

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\\
τῶν θεωριῶν \footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\\*
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\!

\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

With the code provided above one would get the result illustrated on the left side of the image that follows (I only show the bottom of the first page in order to save space). If the `\\*` substitutes the `\\` at the end of the second and third verses of the last stanza (the code below), then I get the result depicted on the right side of the image.

```
\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\\*
τῶν θεωριῶν \footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\\*
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\!
```

Apparently the footnote A moves up and the separation from footnote B is increasing. This behaviour is what I need to eliminate.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I started using the `bottom` option of the `footmisc` package, which holds the footnotes at the bottom of the page.

`\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not `bigfoot` or another package, the problem here is that LaTeX is forced to fill the complete page.  That is only doable, if LaTeX inserts more space between several text blocks.

I just added `\raggedbottom` to allow LaTeX to be able to move the last line on the page up.  I marked the addendum with `%<========`in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek,Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[para]{bigfoot}
\def\extrafootnoterule{\defaultfootnoterule}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}
\def \mylinespacing {1.05}
\expandafter\def\csname @makefnbreak\endcsname{\unskip\linebreak[0]\quad}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Redefines the space above and below the footnote rulers
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\before}{2.52pt}%Space before rule
\newcommand{\after}{10.52pt}% Space after rule
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{%Redefine footnoterule
\hrule width 3cm
\kern \after}
% Change the space kept for rules+spaces around
\advance\skip\footins by \after
\advance\skip\footins by \before
% Not print the after space before the rule
\patchcmd{\@makecol}{\vskip \skip\footins}{\vskip \skip\footins\vskip-\after}{}{}
%load parafootskip
% Not print the after space before the rule
\patchcmd{\MFL@joinrule}{\@tempskipa\skip#5}{\@tempskipa\skip#5\advance\@tempskipa by -\after}{}{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{}

\newcommand{\foota}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\linespread{\mylinespacing}%
\footnoteA{\textbf{\arabic{poemline}} #1}
\endgroup}
\newcommand{\footb}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\linespread{\mylinespacing}%
\footnoteB{\textbf{\arabic{poemline}} #1}
\endgroup}
\newcommand{\footheirm}[1]{%
\begingroup%
\linespread{\mylinespacing}%
\footnoteA+{#1}
\endgroup}

\hyphenpenalty = 10000
\exhyphenpenalty = 10000

\raggedbottom %<===========================================

\begin{document}
\verselinenumbersleft
\settowidth{\versewidth}{ααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααα}

\chapter*{CANON I}
\poemlines{5}

\begin{verse}[\versewidth]

\vin ᾠδὴ . \textit{Θαυμαστὸς ἐνδόξως ποιῶν τέρατα}\footheirm{heirm. α΄ EE 76, n. 108, Andreae}

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τῶν θεωριῶν\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην}\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\!

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τῶν \footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}θεωριῶν\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\\
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\\!

%\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\\*
%τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\\
%τῶν θεωριῶν \footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\
%τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
%τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\\*
%τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
%θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\!

\vin Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν,\\*
τὸν νοῦν τὸν ἄϋλον,\\*
τῶν θεωριῶν \footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὴν σάλπιγγα τὴν θείαν,\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
τὸ στόμα τῆς σοφίας,\\*
τὸν μέγαν θεολόγον\footb{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\*
θείοις ὕμνοις ἀνευφημήσωμεν.\foota{Τὴν πύρινην γλῶτταν}\\!
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

I have no greek installed so I omit the screenshot, please try yourself.  Now you have empty space at the bottom of the page.

If you do not want this you have to play with your line breaks (`\\` vs. `\\*` or `\\>`).

Comment: Interesting point, but I prefer that the footnotes stay on the very bottom of the page. In the case you are suggesting they stick just below the text.